# How to link LoginServlet to Angular?

Tags: angular, servlets

I'm really confused.

I'm a JAVA student and one lecture taught us to set up a web service with Jersey. Then in another lecture we were taught how to communicate with the server through angular. Now I'm trying to connect to the server I built with an angular project and I do not really understand what to do.

In the server there is a login servlet:

```
    package org.chay.CouponSystemJersey;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import ex.InvalidLoginException;
import ex.SystemMalfunctionException;
import facade.AbsFacaed;
import facade.CouponSystem;
import facade.LoginType;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public static final String KEY_FACAED = "facaed";

    private static final String PARAM_LOGIN_TYPE = "loginType";
    private static final String PARAM_PASSWORD = "password";
    private static final String PARAM_USER_NAME = "userName";

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        req.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/login.html").forward(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // For userName -> the inserted user name.
        // For password --> the inserted password.
        // loginType --> The login type , one of : ADMIN, COMPANY, CUSTOMER.
        String userName = req.getParameter(PARAM_USER_NAME);
        String password = req.getParameter(PARAM_PASSWORD);
        String type = req.getParameter(PARAM_LOGIN_TYPE);

        LoginType loginType = LoginType.valueOf(type);

        HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);

        try {
            AbsFacaed facaed = CouponSystem.getInstance().login(userName, password, loginType);
            String pathURI;

            switch (loginType) {
                case ADMIN:
                    pathURI = "WEB-INF/admin.html";
                    break;
                case COMPANY:
                    pathURI = "WEB-INF/company.html";
                    break;
                default:/* CUSTOMER */
                    pathURI = "WEB-INF/customer.html";
                    break;
            }

            req.getRequestDispatcher(pathURI).forward(req, resp);
            session.setAttribute(KEY_FACAED, facaed);

        } catch (InvalidLoginException | SystemMalfunctionException e) {
            resp.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/login");
        }
    }
}
```

Before each action there is a Session Filter that checks whether a user is logged on:

```
package org.chay.CouponSystemJersey;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class SessionFilter implements Filter {

    public SessionFilter() {
        System.out.println("constructor");
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        System.out.println("Filter init was called");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest servletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        HttpSession session = servletRequest.getSession(false);

        if (session == null) {
            HttpServletResponse servletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            servletResponse.sendRedirect(servletRequest.getContextPath() + "/login");
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("Filter destroy was called");
    }

}
```

In the postman request:

> http://localhost:8080/CouponSystemJersey/login?password=1234&loginType=ADMIN&userName=admin

Works well and moves to html page.

In angular I do not really know how to deal with this request:

1. I do not know which type will return the post request (in this example, I set it to return any).
2. The http request does not work.

This is my server at Angular:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { ApiResulte } from '../model/latlong.model';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CouponService {


  private password:string;
  private userName:string;
  private loginType:string;

  constructor(private myHttpClient: HttpClient) {

  };

  public doLogin(){
    let l = {
      password:this.password,
      loginType: this.loginType,
      userName:this.userName
    }

    this.myHttpClient.post<any>("http://localhost:8080/CouponSystemJersey/login?password="+this.password+"&loginType="+this.loginType+"&userName="+this.userName+"",l).subscribe(
        res=>{console.log(res)},
        err=>{console.log(err)}
    );
  } 
};
```

This is a component of html where the client will fill with user information:

```
    <h1>login page</h1>

<h2>to login fill your ditel:</h2>


  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myService.userName"  placeholder="fill your user name">
  <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="myService.password" placeholder="password"><br>
  <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="myService.loginType" value="ADMIN" checked> admin<br>
  <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="myService.loginType" value="COMPANY"> company<br>
  <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="myService.loginType" value="CUSTOMER"> customer
  <br>
  <button (click)="myService.doLogin()">submit</button>
```

This is the error I get:

[image]

Please do not be harsh with me, I'm beginner.
Anything small will help me a lot

**JoHTVS** Is the location correct?

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
    resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
    req.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/login.html").forward(req, resp);

}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
    resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
    // For userName -> the inserted user name.
    // For password --> the inserted password.
    // loginType --> The login type , one of : ADMIN, COMPANY, CUSTOMER.
    String userName = req.getParameter(PARAM_USER_NAME);
    String password = req.getParameter(PARAM_PASSWORD);
    String type = req.getParameter(PARAM_LOGIN_TYPE);

    LoginType loginType = LoginType.valueOf(type);

    HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);

    try {
        AbsFacaed facaed = CouponSystem.getInstance().login(userName, password, loginType);
        String pathURI;

        switch (loginType) {
            case ADMIN:
                pathURI = "WEB-INF/admin.html";
                break;
            case COMPANY:
                pathURI = "WEB-INF/company.html";
                break;
            default:/* CUSTOMER */
                pathURI = "WEB-INF/customer.html";
                break;
        }

        req.getRequestDispatcher(pathURI).forward(req, resp);
        session.setAttribute(KEY_FACAED, facaed);

    } catch (InvalidLoginException | SystemMalfunctionException e) {
        resp.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/login");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I want to show here how in the end I solved the problem:**

When there is an attempt to run two projects at the same time and they are on the same local host there is a problem CORS as noted above.
There are several ways to solve the problem, the best way for me works like this:

You need to open a command prompt (you can perform a search in the task window of the word cmd)

In command prompt, write the following two commands:

> cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
>
> chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session"
>   --disable-web-security`

After the commands, a Google Chrome window will open that does not work according to the CROS policy and we can run two local projects simultaneously.

You can work with this way until the end of the ANGULAR section to see that everything works properly.
Then you can run the following command inside the project terminal in ANGULAR

The following command will compile the Angular project into a folder named **dist** that will contain the whole Angular project as html and some scripts that we can copy into the servlet project.

> ng build --prod

Then the Angular Project and the web service will sit on the same local host and the CROS problem will be resolved.

I hope my explanation is clear that it will help people who have encountered a problem like mine

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, the browser always block requests between two hosts that are not on the same domain.
Your Angular application and your server are on the same domain (`localhost`) but not on the same port.

You have to allow your Angular application to communicate with your server by adding some headers to your server response.
Try to add them in your `doGet()` and `doPost()` methods:

```
resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
```

Comment: I updated the question with the addition of what you said, did I add it to the right place?

Comment: What server do you use?

Comment: Jersey RESTful Web